# Find next 30 days (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date

I am looking for a javascript function which will take one date value and tell me the next 30 days values.

For example, if the current date is 5 August 2011
I would want it to list all 30 days after this:

- 5 August 2011
- 6 August 2011
- .....
- 3 Sep 2011

The function basically takes care of the month days (30 or 31 or 28 etc.)

Is this something I can solve easily?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and write `new Date(year, month - 1, day + i)`.

The Javascript `Date` constructor will normalize out-of-range dates to their proper values, so this will do exactly what you want.
You need to write `month - 1` because months are zero-based.

Here's the code for this [(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/6efPX/):

```
var today = new Date();

var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth();
var date = today.getDate();

for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
      var day=new Date(year, month - 1, date + i);
      console.log(day);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

quick answer: use [`Date.js`](http://www.datejs.com/).  For example you could do `new Date("today + 30 days");` and it will understand :]  It's a pretty awesome library I use on a lot of projects for date kung-fu...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you might want something like this:

```
var nextXDays = function (days) {
    var today = new Date();
    var days = [];
    var day_length = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //the length of a day in milliseconds
    for(var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        days.push(today + day_length*i);
    }
}
var days = nextXDays(30); //return an array of the dates
```

Then, since you have an array of `Date` objects, you can display them in any format that you like.

Comment: This doesn't work, instead of new Date() you need Date.now() and when you do the addition you need new Date(today + day_length*i)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date();
document.write(date);
document.write("<br>");

for (var x=0;x<40;++x)
{
  var d=date.getDate();
  date.setDate(d+1);
  document.write(date);
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

You want to use the built-in date functions. Don't try adding 24*60*60*1000 milliseconds to get to the next day. This assumes that every day is 24 hours long, which isn't true. Consider the days when daylight savings starts and ends.